Where can I find a template for a Brill Journal
I want to write an article for this journal from BRILL Publishing, but I an unable to find on their site or even on the internet a template for it. This is my first attempt to a journal in humanities area.
Not being able to find the templates is somehow a surprise for me, since almost all mathematics, engineering or computer science journals offer some latex package with templates for their journal.
Is there a way to get a template for this journal?

Refer to the Author Instructions - they expect a MS Word document and provide reasonably detailed information on expected paper length, margins, reference formatting, paragraph formatting, etc. Given that the explicitly ask for an editable format (MS Word) I suspect that they do the detailed typesetting after acceptance, which explains the lack of a template. A template is really only useful if you expect the authors to do most or all of the typesetting for you (which is common in CS, but as far as I know much less so in other fields).

It is very counter intuitive for me! I do not even know how to use citations properly in MS Word! And all those foot notes ... where I am suppose to write them? It seems that I have to increase my MS Word knowledge. A template would have helped ...

Rather than having to learn something new, maybe select a different journal?

@Aruralreader Very much doubt any theological journals offer a LaTeX template.

@AzorAhai-him-: Yup, and a great opportunity for OP to make the logical conclusion.

@Aruralreader Your comment is so between irony and genuine advice that I cannot understand it! Do you suggest quitting the mentioned Journal just because it does not have a Latex Template? Or rather increase my MS Word skills and muscle through towards the directions stated in that Author Instructions document?
